# Unity3d Should I cache AndroidJavaObject instance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating simple Android plugin for Unity3D game to show toasts and native popups. When I want to call methods from Java class I use AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject like in Unity documentation:

```
        AndroidJavaObject bridge = new AndroidJavaObject(CLASS_NAME);
        AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
        AndroidJavaObject act = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"); 
        act.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
        {
            bridge.CallStatic(methodName, args);
        }));
```

Unity documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJARPlugins.html "Best practice when using Java plug-ins with Unity") recommended to use using statement like

```
using (AndroidJavaClass cls = new AndroidJavaClass("java.util.Locale")) { 
    using(AndroidJavaObject locale = cls.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getDefault")) { 
        Debug.Log("current lang = " + locale.Call<string>("getDisplayLanguage")); 
    } 
}
```

but said that this is "computationally expensive methods".

Question: Should I cache instances of AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject or not?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the usage.

If you need to call method once or just few times then use the `using` statement so that `AndroidJavaClass` and `AndroidJavaObject`  would be destroyed as soon as possible and free the memory.

If you have to call this method every frame or most of the time, you should **not** use the `using` statement. This will create new instance of `AndroidJavaClass` and `AndroidJavaObject` each time you use it in a `using` statement then destroy it. It will cause Garbage Collector to happen more often and GC running contributes to hiccups or temporary freezing in your game especially on mobile devices (Android in this case).

For example, if the first code example in your question is required to be called every frame then cache them in the `Start` function and use them in the `Update` function. It will clean up when scene is reloaded or when another new scene is loaded:

```
AndroidJavaObject bridge;
AndroidJavaClass jc;
AndroidJavaObject act;

//Cache
void Start()
{
    bridge = new AndroidJavaObject(CLASS_NAME);
    jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    act = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
}

void Update()
{
    DoSomething();
}

void DoSomething()
{
    act.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
    {
        bridge.CallStatic(methodName, args);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought in same way. Will mark question as resolved

Comment: @Programmer Any way to manually deallocate the AndroidJavaObject?